# 75% success, ranges for given sample sizes with 95% confidence

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution

A given task has a 75% chance of success. With 90% confidence, what would be expected ranges of success for
- 10 attempts
- 50 attempts
- 100 attempts
- 1,000 attempts
- 10,000 attempts

very many thanks in advance :)

Comment: "Confidence" is not quite the right term to be using for this question. Perhaps you mean "probability"?  It would help to clarify what you mean by "expected ranges," too, because (1) the meaning of "expected" is unclear and (2) without additional stipulations, there are many valid answers.

Answer (score 0):

In this question, the tasks probably follow a binomial distribution, and

10 attempts: ~ B(10, 0.75)
50 attempts: ~ B(50, 0.75), and so on

With large number of samples (n >= 30), the confidence interval can be approximated using the normal distribution, so use it to estimate for the cases except the first one.Let x denote the number of successful tasks.

For a 90% confidence level, the error α is 10%, 1-0.5α = 0.95, and z = 1.645. 
If $ n = 50, E(x) = 50*0.75 = 37.5, Var(x) = 50*0.75*0.25 = 9.375$, 
and the confidence interval is $37.5 \pm 1.645* \sqrt{9.375}$, or $(32.46, 42.54)$

And for small values of n like 10, it's more difficult to approximate accurately. You can use the Wilson score interval as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Comment: This question is not answered with a confidence interval calculation!

Comment: Hi whuber, do you understand what the confidence in this question means? It seems that the confidence in this question refers to confidence interval.

Comment: The OP uses "confidence" in the title in a non-technical way.  Do not be misled by this misuse of the word: the statement of the problem makes it clear that $75\%$ is a given *probability* rather than a confidence limit to be derived from any data. The second use of "confidence" within the question itself is not quite so clear, which is why I requested further information from the O.P. (who seems not to be forthcoming).